# How to connect locahost with my outside Database

Tags: ssh, database, tunnel

i to want to connect from my Computer to my outside Database .

SSH information from my Web-Host

SSH IP:   ***.224.138.*** 
SSH Port:   65002
SSH Username:   2907*****
SSH Password:   ***********

I have a File on **/var/www/html/provess.php**  which connect to my Database on my Host (it is outside from my Computer) , the code [here](https://codeshare.io/2EXxnP)

With

```
ssh -p 65002 2907***** @***.224.138.***
```

Can connect to my Host .

When try,

In my Firefox , give on SOCKS-Host -> 127.0.0.1 Port: 8080 , to connect .

on Terminal write,

```
ssh -D 8080 -C -N -p 65002 2907*****@***.224.138.***
```

asked from my password

and on the Browser write,

> localhost:8080/provess.php

I to come, Not connection....

I have same to try in localhost (all on my computer , Datebase too..) , and all working gut , Screenshot from the Browser , when write **localhost/provess.php** (but here the name File is prove_comment..) , [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHkQI.png)

How have my File **sshd_config** [here](https://codeshare.io/5PnevQ)

With these Code Check if the remote host allow tunneling.

```
ssh -p 65002 -v -L 3333:***.224.138.***:65002 2907*****@***.224.138.***
```

the tunnel is established correctly .

I want , when write on my Browser **localhost/provess.php**  , it Display the Table with inside the content from my Database(name , email and message) .In a connection with SSH and Tunnel .

Can Please anyone Help me , Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So , People tell me , it is possible easy to making....

I to let my File **provess.php**  on my Website , than Write on my Browser ,

https://myWebsite/provess.php

and....

[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otg0n.png)